# Is there a way to prepend a fixed number of bytes before a std:: stringbuf?

Tags: c++, stl, stream, buffer, stringstream

I’m trying to prepend a 4 byte header to an existing `std::stringbuf` object. For example if data in stringbuf is `‘h’,’e’,’l’,’l’,’o’`  and the header is `‘0x00’,’0x10’, ‘0x00’,’0x0a’`  then I need to change stringbuf to `‘0x00’,’0x10’, ‘0x00’,’0x0a’, ‘h’,’e’,’l’,’l’,’o’`.
I’ve been trying the below approach but it is inefficent because it has three copies of data in `sbuf`, `TextStream` and buff. Using `new char[]` is more problematic because it needs continuous block of memory and I can have very large streams.

Can someone help me by showing me how I can do this in a better optimized way? I mean is there a way to prepend bytes before an existing stringbuf?

```
std::stringbuf CreateStreamWithHeader(std::stringbuf &sbuf)
{
    int i = sbuf.str().size();
    std::stringbuf TextStreambuf;
    uint32_t streamsize = sbuf.str().size();
    char* buff = new char [streamsize + 5]; //Using char buffer is not memory efficient as it needs a big contonuous chunk of memory.

    ZeroMemory(buff, (streamsize + 5)*sizeof(char));

    buff[0] = (streamsize >> 24) & 0xFF; //In my case header needs to contain size of data in sbuf
    buff[1] = (streamsize >> 16) & 0xFF;
    buff[2] = (streamsize >> 8) & 0xFF;
    buff[3] = (streamsize >> 0) & 0xFF;
    strcpy(&buff[4], sbuf.str().c_str()); //strcpy is not the right solution because it will fail if there’s a NULL character in sbuf
memcpy(&buff[4], sbuf.str().c_str(), streamsize);
    TextStreambuf.sputn(buff, streamsize + 4);
    delete []buff;
    return TextStreambuf;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::stringbuf  stringbuffer, finalstringbuffer;
    stringbuffer.sputn("This is a some string for testing", 33);
    finalstringbuffer = CreateStreamWithHeader(stringbuffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you using a `stringbuf` in C++ rather than just a normal `string`?

Comment: What is the actual problem that you're trying to solve? Part of that answer should include what the purpose of those bytes is.

Comment: I’m doing this while encrypting data. The first 4 bytes of the data need to contain the size of the original data. The proc (not written by me) that actually does encryption takes in stringbuf so that is what I’m also using.

Comment: I haven’t worked with stringbuf before but I think that it is not a continuous block of memory while string is a continuous block of memory which means if anything needs to be prepended to string then whole string needs to be copied to a new location or all bytes need to move. I think I’ll be good if I can get to prepend bytes to stream? Since stringbuf is underlying buffer to stringstream, I can get stringbuf from stringstream.

Answer (score 0):

You can, and should, do this without ever prepending:

1. Record the streambuf position
2. Seek forward or write a placeholder of the correct size
3. Write your other data.
4. Seek back to the beginning.
5. Overwrite the placeholder with the final value.

Comment: I did not understand the 5th point.  By step 4 I have added my 4 bytes to the end of stream and am again at the beginning of the stream.But my 4 bytes are now at the end of stream and not at the starting. Did you mean to say that I create a copy of whole stream. If yes then how is it different from what I'm doing currently?

Comment: In step 2 what is the " correct size"? Is it 4 bytes? Then at step 3 I assume you mean that I write my header (4 bytes) but then the header is at the end of data rather than before it.

Comment: @deployX: In step 2, you write a placeholder the same size as your data.  Step 3 is not the header, it is the payload (which might come from some library function, etc, so you don't know the size in advance).  In your code, that `sputn()` call in main() represents Step 3.  Step 4, you measure how much content the library functions added, and seek back to the placeholder.  Step 5 you overwrite the placeholder with the real header.